# sql like first and second

Tags: sql, sql-like

```
address_land
------------------------------------------------|
taitan moudo yan-chi 633, 644; mei-li 759-1, 752
taipei chinying josan 522,666
taidung lugu  a-pei 500-3
```

---

### land_table

```
land   |code
---------------
yan-chi| AD551
mei-li | AG666
jo-sang| EH332
a-pei  | GX112
```

---

I can

```
select address_land from ... where address_land like '%'+[land]+'%'+[land]+'%'
```

how can I save the first [land], AND second [land]?

when I command 'like' taitan moudo yan-chi 633, 644; mei-li 759-1, 752

```
select address_land, land_table.[land] 
from ... ,land_table
where address_land like '%'+[land]+'%'+[land]+'%'
```

I can find the one but not both two?
what should I do?

Comment: like 'first land' or like 'second land'?

Comment: what is [land] in your question? Are all them the colum `land` of table `address_land `, or parameters? Your expected result?

Comment: Hi @李文惠 , welcome to SO or sort of ... Please have a look on how you can improve your questions ... http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: It appears that you are storing two values in one field.  Don't.  That is a significant SQL Anti-Pattern.  Consider storing each value in its own field, or its own row.

Comment: if you modify your where clause from `where address_land like '%'+[land]+'%'+[land]+'%' ` to `where address_land like '%'+[land]+'%'`, you get 3 records instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match one row with multiple rows with a single like. You could try multiple joins to achieve this:

```
select a.address_land, land1.[land], land2.[land]
from ... a
join land_table land1 on a.address_land like '%' + land1.[land] + '%'
join land_table land2 on a.address_land like '%' + land2.[land] + '%'
```

EDIT: This is not a good way to join data in SQL Server, it will not perform well.